# How to fix error on SMTP mail server setup on aaPanel

Tags: server, smtp

I just want to have an SMTP setup on my server using aaPanel. But when I go over these steps I'm facing an error. Why it says `A record parsing failed`

[image]

Well, I have already DNS set up on a Cloudflare.
[image]

But I wonder why I can't get a success message when I click the submit button... Is there any way to fix it? Please, I need your help, and thanks in advance

Comment: I think your host is going to have to solve this problem.   This looks like something you would need root access to the server to fix and not something you can do through your panel account.

Comment: On Cloudflare, turn off proxy for mail.yourdomail.com, wait 30 mins, then try again. It worked for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An A record must be an IP address, not a domain name. It would seem that AAPanel is taking the reasonable step of checking that the input matches the form of an IP address.
(Also, other then your VM, nothing in the Internet will see these DNS records as they are not authorative.  I don't know that you should be adding them, but if you do need to, its likely appropriate to put in the IP address of the VM)